# "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" with simple Javascript plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm having a heck of a time trying to figure out what's going on here, so I figure I'd turn to the masses:

I'm trying to implement this skillset plugin: http://www.jqueryscript.net/chart-graph/jQuery-Plugin-To-Create-Animated-Skill-Experience-Bars-Skillset-js.html

I'm getting the classic "undefined is not a function" error when trying to call the skillset function. One thing to note (not sure if it makes a difference) is this is in ASP.NET's MVC template. Here is are my scripts at the bottom of my layout.cshtml:

```js
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/skillset.js"></script>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

    <script type="text/javascript">

    var object = [

        {

            'headline': 'HTML & CSS',
            'value': 8,
            'length': 9,
            'description': 'Significant experience and knowlage of HTML(5) and CSS functionality and use.'

        },
        {

            'headline': 'JavaScript & jQuery',
            'value': 6,
            'length': 5,
            'description': 'Experience with object-oriented JavaScript. </br> Extended knowlage of DOM manipulation in aiding and extending the UI.'

        },
        {

            'headline': 'Ruby & Python',
            'value': 3,
            'length': 5,
            'description': 'Experience with object-oriented JavaScript. </br> Extended knowlage of DOM manipulation in aiding and extending the UI.'

        }

    ];

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#skillset").skillset({

            object: object,
            duration: 40

        });

    });

    </script>
```

And here is the skillset.js file (located at /Scripts/skillset.js):

```js
(function ( $ ) {

 $.fn.skillset = function( options ) {

  _this = this;

  $.fn.extend({

   isOnScreen: function(){

    var win = $(window);
    var viewport = {
     top : win.scrollTop(),
     left : win.scrollLeft()
    };
    viewport.right = viewport.left + win.width();
    viewport.bottom = viewport.top + win.height();
    var bounds = this.offset();
    bounds.right = bounds.left + this.outerWidth();
    bounds.bottom = bounds.top + this.outerHeight();

    return (!(viewport.right < bounds.left || viewport.left > bounds.right || viewport.bottom < bounds.top || viewport.top > bounds.bottom));
   },

   setRun: function(option){
    hasRun = option;
   },
   checkRun: function(){
    return hasRun;
   }

  });

  var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            object: "",
            duration: 80
        }, options );

  $(this).setRun(false);
  if($(this).isOnScreen() && !$(this).checkRun() ){
   create_trigger($(this));
  }

  function bar_loop(start,value,length){

   var j=0;
   for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){

    setTimeout(function(){

     if(j < value){
      var html = '<div class="full"></div>';
      $(html).appendTo(start).css('width',100/length+'%');
     }else{
      var html = '<div class="empty"></div>';
      $(html).appendTo(start).css('width',100/length+'%');
     }
     j++;

    },settings.duration*i/(length/10));

   }

  }

  function create_trigger(element){

   var key, count = 0;
   for(key in settings.object) {
    if(object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
     count++;
    }
   }

   $(element).setRun(true);
   start = $(element).append('<ul class="skillset-list"></ul>');

   for(var i = 0; i < count; i++){

    start = $(element).find('ul');
    var html = '<li class="skill-'+(i+1)+'""><p>'+settings.object[i]['headline']+' <span class="icon-info-circled" data-info="'+settings.object[i]['description']+'"></span></p><div class="bar"></div></li>';
    html = $(html).appendTo(start).find('.bar');

    var value = settings.object[i]['value'];
    var length = settings.object[i]['length'];

    bar_loop(html,value,length);

   }

  }

  $(document).scroll(function(){

   if($(_this).isOnScreen() && !$(_this).checkRun()){
    create_trigger($(_this));
   }

  });

  $('.icon-info-circled').hover(function(){
   $(this).css('color','#222222');
   $(this).parent().parent().append('<div id="list-info" ><p>'+$(this).data('info')+'</p></div>');
   setTimeout( function(){
    $('#list-info').css({'opacity':0.9, 'bottom':50});
   },100);
  }, function(){
   $(this).css('color','auto');
   $('#list-info').remove();
  });

 };

}( jQuery ));
```

Any help would be so greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is the line of code at which the error happens?

Comment: Oh, it says 322:

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a functionVM56:322 (anonymous function)jquery-1.10.2.js:3062 jQuery.Callbacks.firejquery-1.10.2.js:3174 jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWithjquery-1.10.2.js:447 jQuery.extend.readyjquery-1.10.2.js:118 completed

Comment: And if I click the link in the debug console on that error, it takes me right to this line: 

$("#skillset").skillset({

Comment: Well first thing I'd do is check to see if that "skillset" plugin is being installed successfully - you can type `$.fn.skillset` at the console, and it should be a function (not `undefined`).

Comment: Ahh, it's definitely still undefined. I'm new to MVC on ASP.NET but I have a feeling I'm trying to load it in the wrong spot maybe. However, JQuery and Bootstrap are loading just fine, and they're right above where I'm loading skillset.js. Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: One thing that sometimes happens is that some other boilerplate in your framework may *also* load jQuery. A second load of jQuery will wipe out the original and anything added to it.

Comment: make sure that you are not loading the scripts multiple times..... make sure the files are loaded only once (see that jquery is not in your script rendered bundle! because you have called it separately as well)

Comment: Remove the section  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")  and try again . as @Kalish mentione , you might be loading multiple versions of JQuery libraries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that you are not loading the scripts multiple times..... make sure the javascript files are loaded only once (see that jquery is not in your script rendered bundle! because you have called it separately as well)

Comment: This answer was spot on. I commented out the bundle load and it worked! However, I'm confused because if I comment out my other jquery load, but leave in the bundle render, it doesn't work?

Comment: load the skillset.js after the bundle render, it should work fine. (move skillset.js below your bundle not before it)

Answer (score 1):

@Kalish point is valid and most likely it's the cause of your problem.
To verify that you can view the code of your compiled html and verify what scripts and CSS are loaded. At the same time you can use the developer tool (Depending on your browser) to get more insight info about your compiled html

Comment: That's a good point. Thank you. Obviously I'm a bit new to the MVC world.